# How to add dictionary keys with defined values to a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I'm trying to only add keys with a value >= n to my list, however I can't give the key an argument.

```
n = 2
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
for i in dict:
  if dict[i] >= n:
    list(dict.keys([i])
```

When I try this, it tells me I can't give .keys() an argument. But if I remove the argument, all keys are added, regardless of value

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `.keys()` method of `dict` as you are already iterating `data_dict`'s keys using for loop.

```
n = 2
data_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
lst = []
for i in data_dict:
  if data_dict[i] >= n:
    lst.append(i)

print lst
```

Results:

```
['c', 'b']
```

You can also achieve this using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
result = [k for k, v in data_dict.iteritems() if v >= 2]
print result
```

---

You should read this: [Iterating over Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-for-loops-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filtered_keys = filter(lambda x: d[x] >= n, d.keys())
```

Or using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
filtered_keys = [x for x in d.keys() if d[x]  >= n]
```

The error in your code is that [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns **all** keys, as the docs mention:

> Return a copy of the dictionary’s list of keys.

What you want is one key at a time, which list comprehension gives you. Also, when filtering, which is basically what you do, consider using the appropriate method (`filter`).